# Can someone do something to my website if I posted a snapped image of the header and covered my logo? (On reddit, when explaining a question)

Tags: security, hosting

The question is as it states. I don't want to go on reddit to ask this. Might not be the place to ask a question like this, but I am worried. After I posted my question my wordpress started acting up, loading slowly and eventually just not working at all. Can this be the work of someone else? Or just a hosting problem?

Comment: If the source where you posted your website caused an increase in traffic to your site, then it's likely your hosting plan isn't powerful enough to support the increased traffic flow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my website isn't published yet so that is not likely to be a problem. It was a hosting thing, they had maintenance yesterday, so it is alright now!